# How to make a symlink in Java when running in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, symlink

How to make a symlink in Java/JVM when running in Linux? Are there any other ways to this than using [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or `java.lang.Runtime.exec("/bin/ln -s /some/path symlink")`?

Creating a symlink is very platform dependant, but I mostly care about running on Linux, nice bonus would be if a shortcut would be created in Windows.

Comment: Also: if you want to use `Runtime.exec()`, then make sure to use the version that takes an array, or you get nasty suprises. Also, follow the advice here: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [JDK 7](https://jdk7.dev.java.net/) includes (via [NIO.2](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/)) a class called [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) that provides a [`createSymbolicLink()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) method.

Previous versions don't provide any built-in way to produce that, so JNI or `Runtime.exec()` are your only real options.