# Change java symlink

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables, command-prompt

My `Windows 8` command prompt doesn't see java anymore. I found that in `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` located wrong symlink that I can't change. When I try change I got error:

```
Problem with Shortcut

The name 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\javaw.exe' specified in the Target box is not valid. Make sure the path and file name are correct.
```

When I try to create shortcut I have message:

```
Windows can't create a shortcut here.
Do you want the shortcut to be placed on the desktop instead?
[Yes] [No]
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling the runtime is probably the safest way of restoring the correct symlinks if you aren't confident about fixing them by hand.

Answer (score 17):

Here is how you solve this problem :

- Delete the original symlinks. All the three of them, I think there
  are three.
- Do not create a shortcut. Shortcut and Symlinks are not same.
- Open a command prompt in the same directory and create new Symlinks using the "mklink" command and point it to your JDK install.

Comment: Beware: If you have two different Java versions, you'll also have to change CurrentVersion key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment via regedit in cmd!

Answer (score 7):

If you use java from the command prompt chances are high that you need to have correct JAVA_HOME variable set as well. Some tools depend on it.

To do it - edit the system environment variables:

1. Add JAVA_HOME and point it to the install path of java version you want
   you could also use symbolic link for the folder
2. In "Path" variable find "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;" and replace it with %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Answer (score 0):

First Uninstall the java from your system, after remove the oracle folder in **C:\ProgramData**. Then again reinstall the java. Next click on **javac.bat** in bin folder of jdk.After check with **command prompt** like, `>javac` it will display all the options.then it's working perfectly...

I think it's duplicate of

[How to make a symlink in Java when running in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871748/how-to-make-a-symlink-in-java-when-running-in-linux)